# Detect browser download errors in WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, web, browser

Is there a way to detect download errors once the JS application starts? Like the ones shown here as an example:

[image]

Want to detect JS/CSS file download errors (which may be due to network down, etc.). Say, if I detect any of these failures I can render a error page instead of showing broken pages (due to missing styles etc.). My application uses lots of third party plugins so I won't know which files are being loaded - so can't verify loading of specific styles..

Are there any chrome API callbacks ? I am ok with any chrome-specific solution as that's our only fully supported browser.

For JS errors themselves I can use window.onerror but this seems out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript files, you can use `onerror` to handle 404 errors:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.js" onerror="alert('error');" type="text/javascript">
```

If you want to scope the entire page's resources, you can add an event listener for `error`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        alert('error while loading resources: ' + e.message);
    }, true);
</script>
```

Comment: OP seems to be using xhr, not a script tag, and  [`error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) event doesn't bubble.

Comment: For example, some of the errors are from tinymce plugin which fails to download css when the page is loaded